# Can I use a Calculated Column to Convert a word/prhase to a number

Tags: calculated-column

What formula will calculate/convert a word/phrase to a number? I'm trying to convert 5 frequencies to numbers and this formula works with 2:
`=IF(OR([Frequency]="Annual",[Frequency]="18 Months"),"365","547")`

But adding a 3rd returns an error message:

`=IF(OR([Frequency]="Quarterly",[Frequency]="Annual",[Frequency]="18 Months"),"92","365","547")`

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain the logic what you are trying to achieve? I believe OR cannot have three conditions at once. You have to use nested OR. Can you try this?

```
=IF(OR([Frequency]="Quarterly",OR([Frequency]="Annual",[Frequency]="18 Months")),"365","547")
```

The conditions still evaluate to single boolean value and you can have only two outcomes in the IF condition based on that.

Answer (score 0):

The OR( ) **function** (its not an operator in SharePoint) can have 30 parameters

http://www.viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

But you do not need OR ()

Your Formula has **3** conditions for the IF statement, that doesn't work as a Boolean has only a true/false output

So its:

*disclaimer: off the top of my head*

```
=IF([Frequency]="Quarterly"
    ,"92"
    ,IF([Frequency]="Annual"
        ,"365"
        ,IF([Frequency]="18 Months"
            ,"547"
            ,[Frequency]
           )
       )
    )
```